# Android: TextViews next to each other on different screen sides

Tags: android, textview, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm struggling with `TextViews`. I want them next to each other but in the opposite screen sides. First should be on the left of the screen and the second on the right. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:id="@+id/unit"
                              android:textSize="22sp"
                              android:text="Unit"/>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:id="@+id/unitName"
                              android:text="Km"
                              android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                              android:textSize="22sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried `layout_gravity` and `gravity` and it doesn't work. I was experimenting with `wrap_content` and `match_parent` but still my `TextViews` are just next to each other. I want them in opposite screen sides. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your width to Wrap_content and Linear layout to RelativeLayout and then set alignParent attributes

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Unit"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Km"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add on both TextViews this line

```
android:layout_weight="0.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Unit"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unitName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Km"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use `android:layout_weight=""` and `android:gravity=""`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your layout please take a look

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Km"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```